# calculating volume using functions

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the volume of a cement slab in yards, but i have to put the input numbers in inches, then convert them to yards. I have tried writing my code and it does calculate, but the output that it gives isn't what i had in mind. The answer is wrong. I think it is that I have out the wrong math formula, but i am not sure what is wrong. I want the answer to be 0.62 yards when it runs.

```
# Return cement amount in yards using cubic inches given thickness (t), width (w) and length (l) in inches
#calc_yards_cement (t, w, l)

# Output (print) results of calculating yards given thickness (t), width (w) and length (l) in inches
#print_results (t, w, l)

#5*12= 60 inches
#10*12= 120 inches

#slab1
def calc_yards_cement (t, w, l):
    calc_yards_cement = round(pow(t * w * l,3)/36, 2)
    return calc_yards_cement

print("A cement slab 4 inches thick, 60 inches wide and 120 inches long requires ", calc_yards_cement(4, 60, 120), "yards of cement.")
print()
```

Comment: You have a local variable names similarly to the function it is created in. That said, can you strip all unnecessary code and also provide the exact output, both expected and actual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to translate t, w, l in yards(divide by 36), one by one, and after that to multiply.

```
def calc_yards_cement (t, w, l):
    calc_yards_cement = round(t/36.0 * w/36.0 * l/36.0, 2)
    return calc_yards_cement

print("A cement slab 4 inches thick, 60 inches wide and 120 inches long requires ", calc_yards_cement(4, 60, 120), "yards of cement.")
```

the output

```
A cement slab 4 inches thick, 60 inches wide and 120 inches long requires  0.62 yards of cement.
```